# Azure AD B2C: Disable create button on signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Good afternoon,

I have an issue with disabled buttons on any auth page with custom policies.
For example "Verification email" page at the example looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdyOz.png). "Continue" button is disabled and has grey background

However mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9geBb.png). "Continue" button is disabled as well, however has normal backgroud.

Does anybody encounter with such problem?

My template is

```
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsigninwithpasswordreset">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.4</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

Comment: I guess the Screenshot which you shared is for Password Reset flow and content definition of CombinedSignInSignUp. Please share the content definition of Password flow, then will able to help you.

Comment: @RohitPrasad Thank you for your response. You were right, I only updated "api.signuporsigninwithpasswordreset".
I've updated all ContentDefinitions according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout) and it works as it should

Comment: If you found my comments valuable, please give your upvote.

Comment: @RohitPrasad I am afraid I don't have enough reputation to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ContentDefinition should be updated according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout)